# Crop a triangle from image and place it below the original image CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve this effect using HTML/CSS:

[image]

What I have until now is this 
   http://jsfiddle.net/zxq91ok0/

```
.wrap {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height:250px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:#B2C2CC;
}
.wrap img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}
.wrap:before, .wrap:after {
content:'';
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 50%;
background-color: inherit;
padding-bottom:3%;
}
.wrap:before {
right: 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.wrap:after {
left: 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
transform-origin: 0 100%;
-ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

The problem I face is that instead of plain background color I have another image as a background so I can't figure out how to get rid of the light blue background.

Can you help me accomplish the effect shown on the first image?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't add a triangle in your shape and use it as a mask like that. You need to use SVG shapes and masks or the CSS `mask-image` property ([example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) - beware that's not [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) by all browsers).

Comment: Or JavaScript and a [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).